# Django - Upload file without using form

Tags: django, upload, django-forms, gmail

I have a small email client. I would like to be able to upload files without having to submit a form. So, I have my email form. I would like to, whenever I use the file input button on my form, that file would be uploaded without any reload of the page. The goal is to be able to upload multiple files without a reload of the page, something similar to what happens in GMail.

Every time you click the file input and choose a file, a small progress bar appears with the upload progress, and the page is not reloaded.

I am guessing some JS/Ajax library might help me achieve this? I am using HTML5.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Blueimp](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) has a great jQuery-based throttling file uploader.